# Rendering a UIView into a PDF as vectors on an iPad - Sometimes renders as bitmap, sometimes as vectors

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, uiview

I have an iPad app and I'm trying to generate a PDF from a UIView and it's *almost* working perfectly.

The code is really simple as follows:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile( filename, bounds, nil );
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

This works really well with one weird exception. If the view has been on screen before being rendered to PDF then the UILabels on the view are rendered to the PDF as wonderful vectors. If the view has not yet been on the screen (IE the controller was initWithNib etc but hasn't been pushed into a navigation controller or anything) then the text is rendered as a bitmap at 'ipad' resolution.

It's like the act of getting rendered to the screen sets up the view to be rendered as vectors when I subsequently render it to a pdf context.

Is there some method I can call or property I can set on the view or the layer or elsewhere to mimic this behaviour without having to show the view on screen?

Is it something to do with UIViewPrintFormatter?

Comment: Did you ever get a good answer on this? Also, have you had any issues with the resulting PDF? I have seen a lot of chatter about invalid PDFs and recommendations to use [libHaru](https://github.com/akisute/iPhonePDF) instead, but have not had a chance to test this out for myself.

Comment: No resolution yet, another developer has taken over this problem at my work and also hasn't had any luck.

Strangely it appears as though the old behaviour where it would _sometimes_ render as vectors now isn't the case. It now never seems to render as vectors under any circumstances we've tried to set up. Not sure if this is due to changes in our codebase or from upgrading to a newer version of the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only way I found to make it so labels are rendered vectorized is to use a subclass of UILabel with the following method:

```
/** Overriding this CALayer delegate method is the magic that allows us to draw a vector version of the label into the layer instead of the default unscalable ugly bitmap */
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    BOOL isPDF = !CGRectIsEmpty(UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds());
    if (!layer.shouldRasterize && isPDF)
        [self drawRect:self.bounds]; // draw unrasterized
    else
        [super drawLayer:layer inContext:ctx];
}
```

Swift 5.x:

```
override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
    let isPDF = !UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds().isEmpty

    if !self.layer.shouldRasterize && isPDF {
        self.draw(self.bounds)
    } else {
        super.draw(layer, in: ctx)
    }
}
```

That does the trick for me: labels are unrasterized and selectable in the resulting PDF view, and behave normally when rendered to the screen.

Comment: This did it! We had to change all our labels to the subclassed version, which wasn't too bad. (We only had to change them in the xibs). 

There was an issue with white text labels with a grey background, we had to replace that with a white text over a grey UIView standing in as the label background.

Comment: friendly reminder that you will need to #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> into your UILabel subclass

Comment: I found that I needed to call `setNeedsDisplay` on my `UIView` and its subviews recursively so that when I call `renderInContext:` the views would be redrawn. Otherwise `drawLayer:inContext:` is never called and the previously rasterized layer is used. Also, after `renderInContext:` is called, `setNeedsDisplay` needs to be called recursively again on the view and its subviews so that it will render correctly for display on the screen again.

Comment: i tried this and I get black boxes over my uilabels that I generate. if they are already preset, they work fine. any ideas?

Comment: by already preset, i mean that they are done via gui/ adding it to a storyboard by dragging a label. if i do it programmatically, that's where i get a black rect covering the label.. no idea why that happens.. i tried setNeedDisplay to refresh the current screen drawing

Comment: Black boxes seem to get displayed if you set the backgroundColor of the UILabel.

Comment: A work around to black box problem is to change the condition to:  if (!layer.shouldRasterize && isPDF && !CGColorGetAlpha(self.backgroundColor.CGColor)).   However these labels are then rasterised (but that is better than black boxes!)

Comment: UIView drawLayer is internal, if you override that you won't get in app store. Also, changing the delegate of a layer results in all kinds of crashes. The way to do this is to make a subclass of CALayer, set that as the layer class for your UIView implementation. In your layer subclass you can implement drawLayerInContext

Comment: Oh and by the way, all this effort doesn't result in vectorized pdf in ios 8.3

Comment: This worked for me for getting the text vector based and searchable, but introduced another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850038/uilabel-text-duplicates-in-pdf-when-containing-a-certain-character

Comment: This works LIKE A CHARM for `UILabel` but I'm wondering if there's a way to get it working for `UITextView`?

Answer (score 1):

What about if you add the view on screen but at offscreen coordinates. This seems more like a hack but it might work.

Comment: actually you might be on the right track here. What I have found with ios 8.3 at least is that if you render in context a view which is also on screen it results in a very nicely vectorized PDF, and it shows fine even for labels with backgrounds which would be drawn as black boxes otherwise. But if you render a view which is not on screen, it rasterizes

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest an alternative to mprudhom's great solution: 
Using the `UIString` extensions you can also make the text in the `UILabel` be rendered as font (with select'n'copy support etc.)
This way the glyphs of the font are embedded in the PDF correctly.

To support right and center text alignments as well as the default vertical centered alignment, I had to calculate a bounding box for the `drawInRect` method.

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    BOOL isPDF = !CGRectIsEmpty(UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds());

    if (!layer.shouldRasterize && isPDF) {
        // [self drawRect:self.bounds];

        CGSize fitSize = [self sizeThatFits:self.bounds.size];
        float x = self.bounds.origin.x;
        float y = self.bounds.origin.y;

        if (self.textAlignment == NSTextAlignmentCenter) {
            x += (self.bounds.size.width  - fitSize.width)  / 2.0f;
            y += (self.bounds.size.height - fitSize.height) / 2.0f;
        } else if (self.textAlignment == NSTextAlignmentRight) {
            x += self.bounds.size.width  - fitSize.width;
            y += self.bounds.size.height - fitSize.height;
        }
        [self.textColor set];
        [self.text drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, fitSize.width, fitSize.height) withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:self.textAlignment];
    } else {
        [super drawLayer:layer inContext:ctx];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `drawInContext` rather than `renderInContext`.

Comment: Changing "renderInContext" to "drawInContext" seems to simply draw nothing, ie the resulting PDF is empty. 

I'll keep poking around to see if I can get drawInContext to work.

Comment: FYI further inspection into drawInContext revealed it is meant for overriding if you want to manually handle drawing your view. So unless it's overridden calling it will do nothing.

Comment: You need to also call it for every subview (after applying the proper coordinate system transform).

Comment: Did you ever get resolution on this?

Answer (score -2):

Trying using the view's viewPrintFormatter.

Instead of `[view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];`

try this

```
CALayer* formattedLayer = [view viewPrintFormatter].view.layer;
[formattedLayer renderInContext:pdfContext];
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, most views don't have a proper `viewPrintFormatter` and `view. viewPrintFormatter.view` will return `view`, i.e. not change anything.

Comment: As predicted by MrMage, this doesn't seem to make a difference. The text is still pixelated/rasterized.