# Write PDF text to a PDFContext in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf-generation, core-graphics

It's pretty trivial to draw to a pdf context via:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFile, CGRectZero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(sheet.frame, nil);    
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect text_rect = ...
NSFont *font = ...
NSString * str = @"foo";
[str drawInRect:text_rect withFont:font];

...draw to context...
```

However the text is clearly rasterized...  Is there anyway to actually add *pdf* style text to a pdf file?  So the user can select it, copy it, etc.  Possibly through a library other than core graphics?

Comment: How are you drawing the text? That's the important part. Depending on the API and how things are configured, the text may or may not get rasterized in the PDF.

Comment: Updated the example to show it exactly.  What other APIs are there?  I tried [CALayer renderInContext] and a few others... all rasterized.  What's the library where it's not?

Comment: If you checked the pdf standard specification you'd see that you'd actually need to echo something like `Tj(ABC)` to the file to make it show unrasterized text. I'm not aware of any pdf creation libraries for iOS.

Comment: Like you, I would expect `-[NSString drawInRect:withFont:]` to render the text as text. Not sure why it isn't -- are you using a weird font, or shadows, or color? `-[CALayer renderInContext:]` would definitely rasterize, since CALayers are all about bitmaps; you definitely don't want that.

Comment: [This](http://www.friendlydeveloper.com/2010/08/creating-a-multi-page-pdf-document-on-iphoneipod-touchipad-with-encryption/) May help you

Comment: @KurtRevis using renderInContext with a CAShapeLayer does not rasterize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering a UIView into a PDF as vectors on an iPad - Sometimes renders as bitmap, sometimes as vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423059/rendering-a-uiview-into-a-pdf-as-vectors-on-an-ipad-sometimes-renders-as-bitma)

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible.  [Here's a tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) that shows how to generate and display a PDF document, with text, in iOS 5.

When I downloaded and ran the project, the text did not appear to be rasterized when I zoomed in.  When I opened the generated PDF in Preview in OS X, I could select and copy the text.

This example uses Core Text to draw the text into the CGContext. Should be easy to change `+[PDFRenderer drawText]` to try other methods, if you'd like to experiment.

For instance, I changed it to use code similar to yours, and it worked fine:

```
CGRect text_rect = { 0, 100, 300, 50 };
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
NSString * str = @"Added foo bar";
[str drawInRect:text_rect withFont:font];
```

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using a custom font?  Checking today.

Comment: What I have found with ios 8.3 at least is that if you render in context a view which is also on screen it results in a very nicely vectorized PDF. But if you render a view which is not on screen, it rasterizes. This definitely is some internal core graphics glitch. Something rasterizes everything at some point in the pipeline.