# How to write data to a PDF File in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am a rookie in iOS programing. I am trying to write data present in NSString to a PDF file. The file is being created successfully but when I try to open it, I can't.

```
    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,         NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName = @"WeeklyReport.pdf";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]; 

   [[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
```

I guess my approach isn't correct. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556719/write-pdf-text-to-a-pdfcontext-in-ios

Comment: I am developing a cocoa application and using UIFont throws error...

Comment: @chennupati Use NSFont if it's a Mac app

Comment: @chennupati either you are developing a cocoa app, hence not iOS/iPhone or you are developing a cocoa-touch app and UIFont should work just fine. Make up your mind, properly tag your question and check the search function before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw the string in a PDF drawing context. See this question for details:

[Write PDF text to a PDFContext in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556719/write-pdf-text-to-a-pdfcontext-in-ios)