# UILabel text duplicates in PDF when containing a certain character

Tags: ios, pdf, uikit, uilabel

I'm generating a PDF something like:

1. `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile`
2. `layer.render(in: context)`
3. `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext`

Yesterday, I found a fix to make all text vector-based (basically this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056861/897465).

That worked really well, text is vectors and searchable, etc.

*Except for one irritating thing.*

Everytime a `UILabel` contains the character "Å", the text is kind of duplicated in the PDF, like the image below. Probably there are other characters as well the would cause this. [image]

I've got a small example that demonstrates it below. If you run this in the simulator you'll get a pdf in `/tmp/test.pdf` where you can see the issue yourself.

I guess I should file a rdar, but I would really like some good workaround (good meaning not checking if `label.text` contains "Å"). Since I don't think this is something Apple would fix, considering the whole workaround to begin with (`PDFLabel`).

```
import UIKit

class PDFLabel: UILabel {

    override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
        let isPDF = !UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds().isEmpty
        if !layer.shouldRasterize && isPDF {
            draw(bounds)
        } else {
            super.draw(layer, in: ctx)
        }
    }

}

func generatePDFWith(_ texts: [String]) {
    let paper = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 876, height: 1239))

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile("/tmp/test.pdf", paper, [
        kCGPDFContextCreator as String: "SampleApp"
    ])

    texts.forEach { text in
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        let v = UIView()
        let label = PDFLabel()
        label.text = text
        label.textColor = .black

        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v.addSubview(label)
        v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true

        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        v.setNeedsLayout()
        v.layoutIfNeeded()
        v.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    print("Done!")
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        generatePDFWith([
            "Ångavallen",
            "Hey Whatsapp?",
            "Änglavallen",
            "Örebro",
            "Råå",
            "RÅÅ",
            "Å",
            "Ål",
        ])
    }

}
```

**EDIT**: Little progress in debugging, it seems that the `draw` function gets called two times, and the first time it is drawn a little "off" if it has an "Å" (probably any character larger than the box).

So this fixed it for me (however ugly it may be):

```
class PDFLabel: UILabel {

    var count = 0

    override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
        let isPDF = !UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds().isEmpty
        if isPDF {
            if count > 0 { draw(bounds) }
            count += 1
        } else if !layer.shouldRasterize {
            draw(bounds)
        } else {
            super.draw(layer, in: ctx)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you find a better solution?

Comment: @PeterLapisu not really with `UILabel` I ditched the UILabel and did it directly in the context instead

Comment: hmm ok, feel free than to share maybe your approach as an answer?

Comment: I don't think that's suitable since that has nothing to do with UILabel, which the question concerns and it's not just a matter of a simple change you need to restructure how you render pdfs totally. It involves creating a `UIGraphicsPDFRenderer` and calling `pdfData` with gets you a block with a context that can be used