# Avoiding rasterizing UITextView when exporting to PDF

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, textkit

I'm trying to render a `UIView` to PDF, while maintaining text elements as actual text and not rasterizing them.

I'm using TextKit 2 backed `UITextView` and `NSTextLayoutManager` to provide the contents. However, no matter what I do, `UITextView` gets rasterized into a bitmap.

Here's the basic code:

```swift
let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: pageRect, format: format)

let data = renderer.pdfData { (context) in
    for page in self.pageViews {
        context.beginPage()
        let cgContext = context.cgContext               
        page.layer.render(in: cgContext)
    }
}
```

A page view usually contains one `UITextView`, which uses somewhat advanced layout, so unfortunately I can't just toss it into a single `NSAttributedString` and draw into a CoreText context.

There's [a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423059/rendering-a-uiview-into-a-pdf-as-vectors-on-an-ipad-sometimes-renders-as-bitma) to get `UILabel`s to render themselves as non-rasterized text, and if I understand correctly, it works by just actually drawing them on the current context.

Interestingly, when providing `UILabel` view via `NSTextAttachmentViewProvider` to a text view using TextKit 2, the `UILabel`s **inside** a text view won't get rasterized:

[image: labels are not rasterized]

This hinted that the actual text fragments are the ones that get rasterized when drawing, not the whole view, and I was right. You can enumerate the text fragments and draw them directly on the context, which makes them remain as text rather than become a bitmap:

```swift
page.textView?.textLayoutManager?.enumerateTextLayoutFragments(from: location, options: [.ensuresLayout, .estimatesSize, .ensuresExtraLineFragment], using: { fragment in
    let frame = fragment.layoutFragmentFrame
    fragment.draw(at: frame.origin, in: cgContext)
    return true
})
```

However, this causes other issues, because layout coordinates will be all over the place and not confined to the text view itself (and even more so for my custom `NSTextLayoutFragment` class), and text attachments won't get drawn this way either, but display a skewed placeholder icon.

I'm wondering if there is a way to make `UITextView` and `NSTextLayoutManager` to draw their contents similar to `UILabel`, so the fragments would remain as text in the PDF, rather than become a bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to render a `UITextView` as real text into a PDF using TextKit 2. It currently supports only one text attachment per paragraph, because you apparently can't use `fragment.draw(at:origin:)` to draw attachments.

```swift
let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: pageRect, format: format)
let data = renderer.pdfData { (context) in

    let cgContext = context.cgContext

    textView.textLayoutManager.enumerateTextLayoutFragments(from: location, options: [.ensuresLayout, .estimatesSize, .ensuresExtraLineFragment], using: { fragment in
        
        let frame = fragment.layoutFragmentFrame
        let origin = page.textView?.frame.origin ?? CGPointZero
        
        var actualFrame = frame
        actualFrame.origin.x += origin.x
        actualFrame.origin.y += origin.y
                                
        
        if let provider = fragment.textAttachmentViewProviders.first, let view = provider.view {
            // Draw a text attachment
            let attachmentFrame = fragment.frameForTextAttachment(at: fragment.rangeInElement.location)
            actualFrame.origin.y += attachmentFrame.origin.y
            
            cgContext.saveGState()
            cgContext.translateBy(x: actualFrame.origin.x, y: actualFrame.origin.y)
            view.layer.render(in: cgContext)
            cgContext.restoreGState()
            
            return true
        } else {
            // Draw a normal paragraph
            fragment.draw(at: origin, in: cgContext)
        }

        return true
    })


}
```

I have no idea why Apple decided not to include this as default behavior in `UITextView`, because it seems entirely possible.